# Delay before starting scroll in Jquery Scrollify

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-scrollify

I am using Jquery Scrollify plugin for a project and and I need to have some delay before the slide starts to scroll, so that when the before call back is fired i can run some animations and show some elements fading away and then after delay start to scroll, I know there is a scrollspeed property but thats not what i want, I think it could be achieved with easing but I am not sure how,

Comment: Do you have some jquery code to initiate scrollify?  (or is it only by attributes?)  If so, put that code in a `setTimeout`.

Comment: I think there is no predefined function to get your desired functionality. Check this https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify/issues/207.

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo yeah seems like ur right, ill look into the library code maybe I could tweak something

Comment: This isn't something Scrollify supports. You'll need to find an alternative solution.

Comment: @LukeHaas , I have wrapped some code inside the animateScroll function in a setTimeout and it is giving me the required functionality, at least till now i havent seen anything breaking .